# solr query to sort result in descending order on basis of price

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I am very beiginer in Solr and I am trying to do query on my data. I am trying to find data with name=plant and sort it by maximum price

my schema for both name and price is text type.

for eg let say data is

```
name:abc, price:25;
name:plant, price:35;
name:plant,price:45; //1000 other data
```

**My Approach**

```
/query?q=(name:"Plant")&stopwords=true
```

but above is giving me result  of plants but I am not sure how to sort result using price feild

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: try sort=price desc.../query?q=(name:"Plant")&sort=price desc

Comment: It is giving error solr cant sort on multivalue field

Comment: You cannot use the field with multivalue as true for sorting...it has to be multivalue=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sort param for achieving the sorting.

Your query would be like `q=(name:"Plant")&sort=price desc`

> The sort parameter arranges search results in either ascending (asc)
> or descending (desc) order. The parameter can be used with either
> numerical or alphabetical content. The directions can be entered in
> either all lowercase or all uppercase letters (i.e., both asc or ASC).
>
> Solr can sort query responses according to document scores or the
> value of any field with a single value that is either indexed or uses
> DocValues (that is, any field whose attributes in the Schema include
> multiValued="false" and either docValues="true" or indexed="true" – if
> the field does not have DocValues enabled, the indexed terms are used
> to build them on the fly at runtime), provided that:
>
> the field is non-tokenized (that is, the field has no analyzer and its
> contents have been parsed into tokens, which would make the sorting
> inconsistent), or
>
> the field uses an analyzer (such as the KeywordTokenizer) that
> produces only a single term.

Comment: It is giving error solr cant sort on multivalue field

Comment: Go to the schema file and make the multivalue=false for the price field.